# Can't display 2 different objects on 2 different listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

To clarify before hand this is for an assignment if what I am doing is a bad way i apologize but its all part of the criteria.

Having an issue with WinForms being able to handle having 2 listBoxes display 2 different objects data. I can successfully add data to either one of the listBoxes without and issue but as soon as i try and add data to the other, i am met with this error.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

c was null.

[Photo of Gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGFi2.png)

```
        private void DisplayBook()//display method
        {
            //current index is equal to 0 and increments everytime an item is added ( max of 20)
            for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
            {
                //Book is a class with getters and setters, myBooks is an array
                Book b = myBooks[i];
                //printbook is a print method on the Book class
                lstbook.Items.Add(b.Printbook());
            }               

        }

        private void DisplayCustomer()//display method
        {
            lstcustomer.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
            {
                Customer c = myCustomer[i];
                lstcustomer.Items.Add(c.Printcustomer());
            }
        }
```

example of my two display methods for each listBox.
I have used break points to try and determine the issue but it has been quite elusive, only throwing the above exception on these two lines.

```
Customer c = myCustomer[i];
```

```
Book b = myBooks[i];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the same counter (`currentIndex`) for both `Customer` and `Book`. So when you first add a customer and then a boox, the counter will be 2 but there's only one item in each list.

To make it easier to display the objects, add overrides for the `ToString`method on both your objects, because then we can add the entire object to the listbox:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return this.PrintBook(); // or this.PrintCustomer();
}
```

You could store the objects in a list instead, then you wouldn't have to use a counter:

```
IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

private void AddCustomer(Customer customer) {
    customers.add(customer);
}
```

We could then use a foreach loop to add all items to the listbox, but since we already have all items in a list, we can set that as `DataSource` for the listbox:

```
lstcustomer.DataSource = customers;
```

Comment: I don't have a ToString method, on my objects. On their respective classes I have used a public string that returns a string of text and prints the string into the listBoxes. I have gone about the way I have simply because this is for an assignment and have been asked to do it in this specific way

Comment: I will have a look at this though for future use, seems a lot easier and more concise

Comment: If you need to solve it using your code, and specifically a for loop, then all you should have to do is use a unique counter for each loop (instead of `currentIndex` you would have `currentBookIndex` etc.).